# Can I use a paired t-test when different subjects have different number of data points per condition?

Tags: repeated-measures, t-test, paired-comparisons

I want to compare the effect of a drug (immunomodulator) on antibody levels in a group of patients $(n=18)$. Blood samples were taken pre- and post-treatment in each patient and the means of antibody levels compared for each study subject. At this point I guess that the best and simplest option is a paired t-test.

However, in some cases, I have a different number of blood samples in the pre- vs. the post-treatment group. For example, for one patient I have $16$ samples pre-treatment and $5$ post-treatment.

- Can I still use the paired t-test?
- Should I use the independent t-test?

Comment: For each of the measurements, do you know the ordering? Ie, do you know which of the 16 pre-treatment blood samples was drawn first & when, which 2nd & when, etc? Then all measurements could be placed in time.

Comment: yes I have the date of each blood sample

Comment: Thanks for fast response! yes I have the date of each blood sample... including the pre and post treatment measures. So they can be ordered by time. But I am not sure if the paired T test is the ideal test to use? When I use JMP v9 and do "matched pairs" the program just compare the means of the first 5 pre treatment values (instead of taking the mean from the whole 16 values) vs the mean of the the 5 post treatment values... Also I read that you need the exact number of measures pre and post to perform the paired t test? So I don't know if I can do the independent T test instead?

Comment: The simplest approach is to take as pairs the means of the pre-treatment measurements and the means of the post-treatment measurements, and do a paired t-test on those means.  You should *not* do an independent t-test because the hypothesis you are testing is whether the treatment makes a difference, and the variation between subjects is not accounted for under such a test.  However, even this simple approach is not ideal:  you have captured variability in the repeated measures.  Something like ANOVA would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you so much heropup! How can I manage the fact that I have 16 measures pre-treatment vs 5 measures post-treatment? Does this affect in some way the result?

Comment: How do those 16 probes differ? Can you lose some important information if you average them? Likewise, how do those 5 probes differ? If they are 1 day, 2 days,... later the drug admission then these may reflect the temporal development of the effect, which is potentially important.